# Why UITableView numberOfRowsInSection is called many times?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am requesting data from `CoreData`.

There are two `CoreData` values.

I have this function to set the numbers of rows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("TEST\n")
    return lebensmittel.count
}
```

The output of the print is:

```
TEST

TEST

TEST

TEST

TEST
```

Why do I get the TEST 5 times when the `lebentsmittel.count` returns 2?

Comment: Because it's called various time, whenever it's needed. If you reload data, if you scroll and need to show another "hidden" row it will calculate if there is a row to show, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use this code:-

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
            [ProductListStore removeAllObjects];
            return ProductListStore.count;
    }

remove array element.
```

Answer (score 2):

The delegates methods may be called multiple times when your `UITableView` needs to update anything. By default, it's called very first time the `UITableView` is loaded or updated (reload data).

It's for this that is not a good practice put anything more inside the `numberOfRowsInSection`.

I hope this help you.